# Match line only if next line is an empty Line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm very new to regex, what I'm trying to do is to match a line only if the next line is an empty line.

For example:

1. This is some text
2. ( empty line )
3. This is some text
4. This is some text
5. This is some text
6. ( empty line )
7. This is some text
8. ( empty line )

In the previous example, I would like to be able to select only line 1,5,7.

Is this possible with regex in notepad++?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below positive lookahead based regex.

```
^.*?\S.*(?=\n[ \t]*$)
```

`\S` matches any non-space character. So `.*?\S.*` matches the line which has at-least one non-space character and the following `(?=\n[ \t]*$)` asserts that the match must be followed by a newline character and then followed by zero or more space or tab characters.

**OR**

```
^.*?\S.*(?=\n\n)
```

If you mean empty line as line which don't have any single space or tab characters, then you could use the above regex. `(?=\n\n)` asserts that the match must be followed by a blank line.

[DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/mL6eB8/1)

[DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/mL6eB8/2)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex,

```
(.*)\n\s*\n
```

and replace with

```
\1
```

[Working Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJ9dP5/1)

It uses a concept of [group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11), so here you can use `\1` to use captured group, that is line before newline

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
/(.)*\n\n/
```

If you're looking for an easy way to test / verify regex [rubular](http://rubular.com/) is pretty good.